# Site unavailable while service status is 'running'

Tags: c#, azure

I recently updated my project to use SDK 2.0 and tried to publish it to staging environment. Visual studio reported success but there is nothing at the site generated URL, just a "webpage not available" or whatever is the default browser message for not existing URLs. In Azure management portal however the status is RUNNING and there is even some curve in CPU percentage chart. I updated all references in my role project to be the same as in blank new azure project for 2.0 sdk version, the only new references are added by 'Identity and Access tool' for OAuth purposes. Can anyone tell me what can be possibly wrong or how can i figure this out myself? I enabled diagnostics, but it shows 0 errors in every tab. Of course everything runs fine in my local environment

**upd:** my problem was actually quite simple: something went wrong with port forwarding and i had to add :8080 to url explicitly, so i removed all of my endpoints and added just a simple port 80 one with no internal port set. The accepted answer pointed me the way to discover this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio and Azure Management Portal only report that the server is up and running.  They have no way of knowing if there is an actual issue with the code or deployment.

Webpage not available is not the same as 404 nor is it the same as dns not found.  Webpage not available usually means a server error of some kind.  Most likely some .DLL's are missing from deployment

If you are running on WebRoles, you can RDP into the server and look into the Windows Event viewer to see if any errors occur

Alternatively, you can turn off custom errors via web.config (check this link out for sample directions: http://www.serverintellect.com/support/programming/custom-errors.aspx )

At the end of the day, you need to find out what is the real cause of the issue

Comment: I've set 'copy local' to true on all references, still no effect. I used rdp to see event viewer, not sure what i should check there, i found some errors in azure log saying "could not locate role {package-url}.{my-role-name}_IN_0 in container", any suggestions?

Comment: can you navigate to the site from inside the RDP'ed machine? what errors are you seeing?

Comment: the same 'page not found', or is there any other way to navigate except entering url directly in browser?

Comment: "page not found" or "page cannot be displayed"?

Comment: cannot be displayed, like it is from any other pc

Comment: yeah, there could be alot of possibilities... I'd try browse the site from IIS Manager - it should hopefully give you more meaningful error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34942/discussion-between-igorek-and-oleg-golovkov)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following in your web.config. Mine is added just before the line

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm" mode="Off">
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="InternalError.htm" />
</customErrors>
```

If you are using web.config transforms and have a web.debug.config you add the following code to it:

```
<customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="GenericError.html" xdt:Transform="Replace">
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="InternalError.htm"/>
</customErrors>
```

You still have to make sure you have a custom errors section in your web.config for the replace to happen.